100% CPU usage when using xrdp
I have a PC (Debian Bookworm with ATI Graphic card) that i use both as a desktop and to remote in.
When I use 3D apps like Google Earth, I have noticed that if I use directly my PC, the 3d graphics are nice and fluid but when I do the same remotely (XRDP), the CPU is to the roof and the graphics are slow.
It seems to me that xrdp is not using my graphic card, is that possible ? Any ideas on how to change that ?
